# error after reply to a thread in message boards portlet

Tags: liferay, liferay-6, messageboard

In liferay portal 6.2 CE-GA2, I used message boards portlet. In this portlet I create a thread and then I reply to that thread. After every reply I have these messages in the `catalina.out` log file:

```
 17:18:01,520 ERROR [http-bio-80-exec-575][IncludeTag:129] Current URL /web/knowledge-management/wiki/-/message_boards/message/109006 generates exception: null
    java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.jsp.html.portlet.message_005fboards.view_005fthread_005fmessage_jsp._jspService(view_005fthread_005fmessage_jsp.java:726)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    at com.liferay.portal.servlet.DirectRequestDispatcher.include(DirectRequestDispatcher.java:57)
    at com.liferay.portal.servlet.ClassLoaderRequestDispatcherWrapper.doDispatch(ClassLoaderRequestDispatcherWrapper.java:78)
    at com.liferay.portal.servlet.ClassLoaderRequestDispatcherWrapper.include(ClassLoaderRequestDispatcherWrapper.java:53)
    at com.liferay.taglib.util.IncludeTag.include(IncludeTag.java:295)
    at com.liferay.taglib.util.IncludeTag.doInclude(IncludeTag.java:192)
    at com.liferay.taglib.util.IncludeTag.doEndTag(IncludeTag.java:83)
    at org.apache.jsp.html.portlet.message_005fboards.view_005fmessage_005fcontent_jsp._jspx_meth_liferay_002dutil_005finclude_005f0(view_005fmessage_005fcontent_jsp.java:2972)
    at org.apache.jsp.html.portlet.message_005fboards.view_005fmessage_005fcontent_jsp._jspService(view_005fmessage_005fcontent_jsp.java:2322)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    at com.liferay.portal.servlet.DirectRequestDispatcher.include(DirectRequestDispatcher.java:57)
    at com.liferay.portal.servlet.ClassLoaderRequestDispatcherWrapper.doDispatch(ClassLoaderRequestDispatcherWrapper.java:78)
    at com.liferay.portal.servlet.ClassLoaderRequestDispatcherWrapper.include(ClassLoaderRequestDispatcherWrapper.java:53)
    at com.liferay.taglib.util.IncludeTag.include(IncludeTag.java:295)
    at com.liferay.taglib.util.IncludeTag.doInclude(IncludeTag.java:192)
    at com.liferay.taglib.util.IncludeTag.doEndTag(IncludeTag.java:83)
    at org.apache.jsp.html.portlet.message_005fboards.view_005fmessage_005fdefault_jsp._jspx_meth_liferay_002dutil_005finclude_005f0(view_005fmessage_005fdefault_jsp.java:1997)
```

How an I solve this issue?

Comment: In addition to my answer: Please read this article and add the information suggested there: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/141823/why-is-cross-posting-wrong-on-an-external-site

Answer (score 1):

It depends on how deep you want to go: You can analyze where the NullpointerException happens and see if there's an issue that is easy to fix. You can also check the issuetracker and commits that have been made to the portal since then and backport any fix that has been made in a later version (if it's already fixed)

That leads me to my actual recommendation: I'd recommend to upgrade to the recently released GA6 and check if it still happens there. Chances are that the issue is long fixed and a simple update helps you to get rid of this message. If it's fixed: Party. If not: At least you're on the latest version and have probably fixed a few security issues (and definitely a few other issues) on the way.